# What is the difference between these sound icons in the notification bar?

Tags: cyanogenmod, notification-bar, vibration, volume, mute

When I want to change the volume on my phone, I can press the icons in the notification bar to toggle between vibrate only, silent and normal volume.

However the latter one appears to have two possible icons with only a very subtle change:

[image]

Given that they can't both do exactly the same, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one on the left signifies "ring and vibrate" mode, the one on the right is "ring mode". If you choose the first your phone will vibrate as well as ring for an incoming call. If you choose the second, it will ring only.

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but you can match up the icons with their respective .png files in the CM source as a confirmation of this. It's somewhat hard to see in a browser since they're white icons, but nonetheless:

- [ic_qs_ring_vibrate_on.png](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-11.0/packages/SystemUI/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_qs_ring_vibrate_on.png)
- [ic_qs_ring_on.png](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-11.0/packages/SystemUI/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_qs_ring_on.png)

The name is intending to convey (for example, using the second icon) **ic**on **q**uick**s**ettings **ring on**.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be completely impossible to find any documentation on the web as to what the icons mean - so much so that I actually had to use Photoshop to modify the left image to create the right.